# Счётчик объектов

Tags: java

Как создать в конструкторе объекта счётчик, который будет вписывать в поле объекта номер его создания? То есть первый объект имеет номер 1, следующий-- 2...

Answer (score 7):

```
class Counted {
    private static final AtomicInteger COUNTER = new AtomicInteger(1);

    private final int id;

    public Counted() {
        id = COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(new Counted().getId()); //1
    System.out.println(new Counted().getId()); //2
    System.out.println(new Counted().getId()); //3
}
```

Использование `AtomicInteger` гарантирует атомарность инкремента и предотвращает различные ошибки при многопоточном использовании.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте так

```
class MyClass {

    private static int counter;

    public MyClass() {
        //...
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getNumOfInstances() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28947625/5330439)

Comment: Здесь конструктор заменить на блок инициализации и получим более универсальный код.

Comment: "счётчик, который будет вписывать в поле объекта номер его создания" - это несколько иное, чем подсчет общего количества объектов

Answer (score 4):

Используй static переменные, в то время когда у каждого объекта свои личные нестатические переменные, static переменные существуют на уровне класса, т.е к ним можно обращаться без создания объекта, соответсвенно что для всех объектов они будут одинаковыми.

Answer (score 1):

static для всех один
но если номер каждого то final

```
public class TestGrowSize {
private static int grow;
private final int numberCreation;

public TestGrowSize() {
    grow++;
    this.numberCreation = getGrow();
}

private int getGrow() {
    return grow;
}

public int getNumberCreation() {
    return numberCreation;
}
```